# Clarify Django Choices Mechanics

Tags: python, django, oop

Assume I want to make a booking in a building and the choices change based on the floor chosen.

In my **forms.py** I have

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField()
  room = forms.ChoiceField()

  def __init__(self, room_choices, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['room'].choices = room_choices
```

and in **views.py**

```
def book_room(request):
  choices = Choices.all().list_values('rooms').filter(floor=floor)
  room_choices = []
  for c in choices:
    room_choices.append((c, c), )

  booking_form = BookingForm(room_choices)
```

My question is, what is the mechanics of this? In particular, what does the `def __init__` and the 4 parameters of the methods mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Python question than a Django question, as it looks at object inheritance and initialization more than anything else.

Here's the short version:

`__init__` is a method that gets called when initializing an instance. It's not actually a constructor (that's called `__new__`), but when you do something like

```
booking_form = BookingForm(room_choices)
```

`__init__` will be called after the constructor.

By calling `super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` you allow initializations to bubble up the inheritance chain. In this case, you allow `forms.Form` to do all the initialization it needs to do, which includes defining the form and setting up the fields you defined.

After the fields are defined on the `Form` instance, you override the choices on the `room` field. If you'd try to switch those two lines so that the override takes place before the parent initialization, you'd get a `KeyError` as `self.fields` doesn't exist at that point.

As for the params:

- `self` is a reference to the current instance, that has to be passed to every instance method. This is how Python deals with instance methods (it's the equivalent of `this` in Java)
- `room_choices` is your param
- `*args` and `**kwargs` are Python's way of dealing with arbitrary parameters.

For example, if you'd have something like

```
def foo(param1):
    pass
```

and you called `foo(1, 2, a=5)` you'd get an error about the number of arguments. However, if you defined your method like this:

```
def foo(param1, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

and you called the same `foo(1, 2, a=5)`, args would now be a list `[1]` and kwargs will be a dictionary `{'a': 5}` and you would obviously not get any errors.

`*args` and `**kwargs` are especially useful when you don't want to care about all the parameters the parent method that you are overriding has - as it is in your case here, where `forms.Form.__init__` has a whole bunch of parameters - which you don't touch. You just add your parameter in front of them, and `*args` and `**kwargs` take any other potential parameter up the inheritance chain.